# Restoring setings in Windows 7 after Dual mode with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, sound, windows-7, touchpad

I am a new user of Ubuntu. Until recently I used only Windows 7 on my computer. Ever since I set up Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my computer to run in Dual mode with Windows 7, I have noticed the following problems in Windows 7:

1. I cannot disable the mouse touchpad by just holding the Fn key and pressing the disable-touchpad (on the F9 key). In order to disable it, I go to the Control Panel and press Apply on the preference of disabling the touchpad when the mouse is connected. The annoying part is that I have to do this procedure after every single restart of Windows.
2. Almost after every single restart of Windows, the computer does not play sounds and music through headphones when I connect them. Curiously, the sounds and musics are OK when the headphones are not connected.

It is important to add that none of these problems occur in Ubuntu, but they started in Windows only since the day I put Ubuntu on my computer.

Is there something I am missing? Maybe there is a way to restore Windows settings so as to overcome these problems? And are there any other problems of Dual-mode that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The OSes, Windows and Ubuntu runs independent of each other.  The difference after installing Ubuntu is the boot manager.  The boot manage will load the OS, and from there it's up to the configuration of the OS, as to how it behaves.

Windows does not poll the Ubuntu partition while it's running because Windows can't read the Ubuntu file system.  While Ubuntu could poll (read) the Windows partition, it doesn't.  It reads the Ubuntu configuration from the Ubuntu installed partition.  Making changes to Windows will not affect it's partition and vice versa.

The bottom line is that you will have to describe your Windows problem to a Windows support group.  Keep in mind that if you mention Ubuntu, it might confuse the issue.  They might say you're having a problem because of Ubuntu (a similar deduction that you inferred).

You can configure how Windows defaults while Windows is actual running.  The Windows gurus will help you with this configuration.  If you were having problems with the defaults in Ubuntu, then this would be the pace where the Ubuntu gurus hang out.

Check a group such as http://superuser.com for help with configuring Windows defaults with subjects such as sounds and mouse behavior.

Comment: Many years ago we saw a similar issue with a modem issue. We swore up & down that Windows & Ubuntu used different drivers and it could not be different. But it turned out that one driver was able to set a parameter in the modem that was saved across reboots, and the other driver did not reset it. It was a bug in Windows, but I think Linux had to update its driver to reset parameter. But highly unusual.  Best to check Windows issues in Windows forum. Is issue the same when you do a full hard/cold boot? Not a warm reboot? If laptop remove battery so system is starting from total cold settings.